# Mockito testing DAO in createCriteria get NullPointerException

Tags: java, mockito

i am trying write test for dao layer. I work from hibernate, and when i trying testing my method `getAll` i get exception `NullPointerException` in row from `createCriteria` and i don't know how solve problem.

This is my exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dao.UserDaoTest.testFindAll(UserDaoTest.java:69)
```

This is my testing class:

```
@Mock
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@Mock
private Session session;
@Mock
private Transaction transaction;
@InjectMocks
private UserDaoImpl userDao;

private User user;

@Before
public void setUpUser(){
    user = new User();
    user.setName("is name");
    when(sessionFactory.openSession()).thenReturn(session);
    when(session.beginTransaction()).thenReturn(transaction);
}
@Test
public void testFindAll(){
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    userList.add(user);
    when(session.createCriteria(User.class).list()).thenReturn(userList); //NullPointerException
    List<User> userList1 = userDao.findAll();
    assertThat(userList1, is(userList));
}
```

This is Dao class:

```
private Session session;
private Transaction transaction;
public List<User> findAll() {
    List<User> userList = null;
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    transaction = null;
    try{
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        userList = session.createCriteria(User.class).list();
        transaction.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (transaction!=null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return userList;
}
```

Comment: You have to stub `createCriteria` to return something. Then you have to stub that something to return a `list`. There are no shortcuts.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I need create field Criteria in DAO class for stub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this in testFindAll()

```
Criteria aCriteria = Mockito.mock(Criteria.class);
when(session.createCriteria(User.class)).thenReturn(aCriteria);
when(aCriteria.list()).thenReturn(userList);
```